# Default Transactional Emails containing Var_Grid

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-emails

In the default transactional emails admin panel there is a function within an email called var_grid.

It populates with details like "Wishlist Contents" and such.

However the format is a bit archaic and ancient and i wish to change the way that it appears, spacing, lines etc.

Any idea where this information is stored so i can edit it? I thought itd be in a CSS file somewhere but ive had no luck in finding it.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

To change the look for any email tempalte, the stylesheet file are available into this place.

```
skin/frontend/Your_Theme/css/
```

There are multiple file like this.

```
1. email-inline.css
2. email-non-inline.css
```

Becarefull while make these changes, because it affect all other email if the same class use.